# Pass variable to props option in vue

Tags: vue.js

I was using [this plugin](https://github.com/lolitaframework/vue-trading-view) to embed the trading view chart in my website

The following is my code:

```xml
<div class="chart">
  <template>
    <div class="hello">
      <VueTradingView style="height: 250px;" :options="{
          autosize: true,
          symbol: [this.tvmarket],
          interval: '15',
          timezone: 'Asia/Singapore',
          theme: 'dark',
          toolbar_bg: '#f1f3f6',
          enable_publishing: false,
          hide_side_toolbar: false,
          allow_symbol_change: true,
          show_popup_button: true,
        }" />
      </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

The page is not loading the right symbol occasionally. Sometimes it can parse the variable 'BINANCE:BTCUSDT' but sometime it can't. How can I pass the variable to the options correctly?

Comment: Hi, I think you should not pass symbol as an array. and Is `this.tvmarket` is defined in data?

Comment: @YashMaheshwari I'm not familiar with vue, how can i declare properly? yes, it is defined in data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```xml
<div class="chart">
  <template>
    <div class="hello">
      <VueTradingView style="height: 250px;" :options="{
          autosize: true,
          symbol: tvmarket,
          interval: '15',
          timezone: 'Asia/Singapore',
          theme: 'dark',
          toolbar_bg: '#f1f3f6',
          enable_publishing: false,
          hide_side_toolbar: false,
          allow_symbol_change: true,
          show_popup_button: true,
        }" />
      </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: cannot use {{ }} within "{ }" i guess

Comment: @ChristineOng sorry my bad, try without the `{{ }}` just like how I updated it.

Comment: Yes this will probably work. **However** creating in-line object in template to pass to prop is very bad advice. Maybe not important in this case as the component is just a tiny wrapper around pure JS lib but in all other cases this should be avoided. Because the new object is created on each render and as a result the component will be re-rendered every time. Do not do this!

Comment: Understand. I'm not familiar with vue and was thinking to find a quick fix for wrapping the tradingview plugin for each page.